# Retreiving facebook authtoken

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, flask

I'm trying to make a simple page with FB authenticating and retreive some info about a user. The trouble is I only can get to the token in case the user is already authorized and logged in.

In case they are not, the login window pops up and after I authorize it (I remove the app beforehand) I get no response/reply. So only `not authorized` gets logged in the console but then nothing happens. Only when I reload the page I get the token `ajaxed` on my other url. Is it problem in the script or is it normal?

Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <script src="static/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"> </script>
<script src="sendJSON.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
      attachLoginStatusHandler(); 
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



  function attachLoginStatusHandler() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log("Known user");
    console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
    console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);

     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:JSON.stringify(response),
                async:true,
                // data: JSON.stringify({help:"please"}),
                url: "/receive",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",});

  } else {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app

    console.log("Not authorized");
    FB.login(function(response) {

   if (response.authResponse) {
     var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
     console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_likes,user_friends'});

  };
    });
}


</script>
    <div class="fb-login-button" onClick="fblogin"  scope="public_profile,email,user_likes" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: _"Only when I reload the page I get the token ajaxed on my other url."_ - well you are not doing that in case the user has to login first - you’re only doing that inside your `FB.getLoginStatus` callback, but if that initially determined there was no logged-in user, then you call FB.login, but you’re doing no AJAX request in that case. So of course the token will only be AJAXed to your server, when you reload the page, and this time `getLoginStatus` returns an already logged-in user.

Comment: FYI, you should not nest FB.login into asynchronous callbacks ... if you do not call it on _direct user interaction_ (such as a click), then there is a high chance the popup will be blocked by the browser.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for a reaction. So where should I put it, please? I've been playing around with that, but to no vail :/

Comment: You should have a login link/button, that calls FB.login on click. Let the user request login if the want to, don’t try and trigger it automatically. The SDK can automatically recognize users that have logged in to the app before, set `status: true` for that during initialization.

Comment: isnt that the `<div class="fb-login-button" onClick="fbogin"></div>
` line that does that? And would I put the AJAX bit in response of that?

Comment: You can either use that button, or FB.login. Both at the same time does not make much sense.

Comment: when I hide the <div> button, it never gets shown now. I thought FB.login invokes the button?

Comment: No. The button invokes the login popup, FB.login invokes login popup. They are two different ways of triggering login. When you hide the button and want to use FB.login, then you must call the latter yourself. (Again, when the user clicks something, otherwise it will get caught in the popup blocker.)